# Views have indention after opening storyboard in xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I want to upgrade my `iOS 8` App to `iOS 10` (In House App). After opening the project in `Xcode 8` and running the app on an iPad/Simulator all custom views have indention from the navigationbar. (`UITableViewController` do not have this Problem.)

**View as seen in IB**
This is the `View` in the Interface Builder.
[image: View as seen in IB]

**These are the settings in the inspector**

[image: Settings in Inspector]

**View in Simulator**
As you can see, the border of the "P"-Symbol has an unintended indention. The TableView Section Header is also not visible in the simulator.
[image: View in Simulator]

> So my Question is: How can I fix this? I tried to set the Storyboard Document type to Xcode 7.

Comment: Uncheck the Adjust Scroll View insets in your storyboard. There are at least 10 such questions. Please close this question if the above mentioned answer satisfies ur requirement

Comment: It is not working. I'm not using auto layout, because the device circle is known and no one is paying for it.